# Is it true that a projective Kähler manifold of general type has a smooth canonical model and has no singular fibers?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, kahler-manifolds

A projective Kahler manifold $X$ of general type is a manifold which is projective and whose canonical bundle is big and nef. Let $\Phi: X \to X_{can}$ denote the map from $X$ to its canonical model. Is it true that the canonical model of $X$ is always smooth and $\Phi$ has no singular fibers?

Comment: No, this is already false for surfaces. Where did you get such ideas?

Comment: Actually each projective manifold is Kähler due to the existence of Fubini-Study metric. So Kähler assumption is superflous.

Answer (score 6):

As explained in the comment by abx, this is definitely false already for surfaces.

In fact, the canonical model of a minimal surface of general type might contain some mild isolated singularities (Rational Double Points, aka Du Val's singularities) coming from the contractions of some special configurations of $(-2)$-curves.

You can find (much) more details in the classical paper

E. Bombieri: [**Canonical models of surfaces of general type**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BF02685880), *Publ. Math., Inst. Hautes Étud. Sci.* **42**, 171-219 (1972). [ZBL0259.14005](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0259.14005).